# VisitorIdentification.js not loading on page

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore 10.1.3 with SXA.

The default `SxaLayout.cshtml` has the line `@Html.Sxa().VisitorIdentification()`.

When I check the view source of any page in our DEV environment, the following lines are missing.

`<meta name="VIcurrentDateTime" content="638374437286915946" />`
`<meta name="VirtualFolder" content="/" />`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/layouts/system/VisitorIdentification.js"></script>`

But they are rendered in the PRD site.

Are any config settings missing in DEV?

Comment: If you check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` does your DEV environment has `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` both set to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

If you check `/layouts/system/visitoridentification.ascx` control is a condition that has to be true then only it renders the `VisitorIdentification.js`.

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>

<%  if (Sitecore.Context.Diagnostics.Tracing || Sitecore.Context.Diagnostics.Profiling)
    {%>
<!-- Visitor identification is disabled because debugging is active. -->
<%
    }
    else if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ContactClassification.IsAutoDetectedRobot(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact.System.Classification))
    {
      string virtualFolder = "";
      if (Sitecore.Context.Site != null)
      {
        virtualFolder = Sitecore.Context.Site.VirtualFolder;
      }
%>
<meta name="VIcurrentDateTime" content="<%: DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks %>" />
<meta name="VirtualFolder" content="<%: virtualFolder %>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/layouts/system/VisitorIdentification.js"></script>
<%
    }
%>
```

As per condition if the Tracker is active and the VisitorClasification == 925 (Bot - Auto-detected) then the VisitorIdentification.js will be added.

If you want to check quickly, follow the below steps.

1. Go to `\layouts\System\VIChecker.aspx` file
2. Add `<% Tracker.Current.Session.SetClassification(925, 925, true); %>`.
3. Open a new incognito browser and load the site.
4. View page source from the browser to validate it.

Reference:
[Visitor identification using the robot detection component](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/visitor-identification-using-the-robot-detection-component.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added that code in VIchecker.aspx and there is o change in the page. The visitoridentificaton.js still doesn't render. What should I be expecting from your suggestion.

Comment: Those steps are just to validate the condition works fine. The VisitorIdentification control only outputs the blocking Javascript once - at the initial stage where the system has "auto detected a robot". Once it is satisfied that the session is not a robot, it outputs blank content. Check these links for more details. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/does-visitoridentification-really-need-to-be-in-the-head-element https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17430/missing-visitorindentification-js-script-randomly-when-loading-with-azure-cdn